# Can't get program to read information in textbox

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, textbox

I'm having issues with visual basic when I try to get my program to read a line of output in a Textbox field.

```
Private Sub txtConsole_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If (txtConsole.Text.Contains("[download] 100.0%")) Then
        ProgressBar1.Increment(100)
    End If
End Sub
```

I thought the code would allow the progress bar to appear at 100% once the "[download] 100.0%" appeared in the TextBox, but it doesn't work at all.

This program is a GUI for a command line only program and it passes commands from the GUI to that program.  Currently, for the log, I'm using StreamOutput, but my knowledge with programming is very limited.

Comment: This code is not enough for us to reproduce a problem since we cannot see the whole picture. To start with: Show us where (in what method) this code is located, and please also give us some sample input (copy-paste) from the text box.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where to start for what method or what sample to give, so I pasted the entire source code here:  [link](https://pastebin.com/29xrGrR2)

Comment: _"Where to start"_?? How about where this code is actually located? -- Now that I see that it is located in `TextChanged` we can rule out that the code isn't running. **EDIT:** Found the problem. See below.

Comment: There is no context for that code - *where* is it?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: line 132.  @Visual Vincent - here's an output of the program log: [link](https://pastebin.com/W6Q4ynvH) - Line 21 and/or Line 38 should apply for that code

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the [**`Handles` clause**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/handles-clause):

```
Private Sub txtConsole_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles txtConsole.TextChanged
```

Without it `txtConsole_TextChanged` is just a regular method. The `Handles` clause adds the method to the specified event's (in this case `TextChanged`) event handler list.

Comment: I added the "Handles txtConsole.TextChanged" at the end of that line and the program still will not move the progress bar up based on the information displayed in that output log.  Would you know of an easier way to get this progress bar to function properly?

Comment: @JRV : Not really. Are you sure it always says `[download] 100.0%`? Based on your log it also appears to say `[download] 100%`. Try adding a breakpoint on the `If`-line to see if the code executes at all.